# Paypal custom variable solution

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to using paypal as payment for my site.

My site only sell a virtual currency, like "Diamond" in Online game.

So after reading i starting to use Express Checkout for Digital Goods, Is that right ? or i must other payment method ?

Then my question is when using Express Checkout for Digital Goods, how to pass custom variable ?

Let say i want to pay user_id, diamond_id, and some other variable from my database to the paypal api. It seem like paypal don't support custom variable to pass on the api call. I want after user complete the payment, then Paypal notify my server that the payment is complete by user_id and some other variable that i pass, so easy for me to know the detail.

after searching i find some solution,

1. First solution is to store "TOKEN"(Generated from "SetExpressCheckout" Method) and my custom variable which is belong to the TOKEN in the database, Then after payment complete paypal will notify my server the same TOKEN saved before. So i will query based on the TOKEN.
2. Second Solution is using get style in RETURNURL variable http://www.mysite.com/successpayment.php?user_id=13&diamond_id=88 So i will easy to grab the GET variable.

Which solution is right ? Is there any solution ? and how to secure the payment confirmation, i mean if someone know and hack my returnurl.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

if you are using the [PAYPAL EXPRESS CHECKOUT NVP API](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_api_reference) and the class **[SetExpressCheckOut()](https://www.x.com/paypal-apis-setexpresscheckout-php-5.3/nvp)**

**Referring payment authentication**

```
$paypal = new SetExpressCheckout($totalPrice);
```

*This class caller instantiates the method you’ll use to set up the parameters required for redirecting the customer to Paypal and back. A variable of the total price has to be set to 
complete the initiation of this class.*

```
    $paypal->setNVP("RETURNURL", "http://yourURL.com/confirm.php");
    $paypal->setNVP("HDRIMG", "http://yourURL.com/image.jpg");
    $paypal->setNVP("EMAIL", "$userEmail"); // customer's email
    $paypal->setNVP("AMT", $totalPrice);
    $paypal->setNVP("SHIPPINGAMT", "32");
    $paypal->setNVP("CUSTOM", "Anything you want to put");  // user_id, diamond_id
    $paypal->setNVP("INVNUM", $uniqueID); // your Order number this include the id of your order  (order table  will also have user_id, diamond_id related to the order so you will automaticaly get them once you send the orderid  )
    $paypal->getResponse();
```

*Before you submit for a transfer to Paypal, know that there are optional values you can send with the `setNVP()` function, to customize the payment process. All values that can be found, by default, in the `etc/NVP/SetExpressCheckout.ini file`.
`getResponse()` sends the user’s browser to Paypal for authentication of credit information. Specifically to a URL that you’ll have to variably set between test mode (sandbox) and live, in the file named etc/NVP/PayPalNVP.ini.*

**Completing the Sale**

```
$paypal  = new GetExpressCheckoutDetails;
$details = $paypal->getResponse();
```

**DoExpressCheckoutPayment()**

```
$payment  = new DoExpressCheckoutPayment($totalPrice);
$response = $payment->getResponse();
```

**Check Status**

```
if ($response['PAYMENTSTATUS'] == 'Completed') {
    # process information
}
```

**Displaying results from getResponse**

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($details);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($response);
```

Detail Description on [this](http://moorberry.net/blog/paypal-express-checkout-nvp-api/)

Comment: @champ the links are not working anymore, do you have any workable links? I am also looking for  a custom variables solution and an example of a order table would be awesome, regards

Answer (score 1):

The PayPal API does allow you to send custom data. And no, never ever use the return URL to give the user what they've paid for. Anyone could go to that URL.

The way the PayPal API works is you (usually) send a form to PayPal, with a load of hidden fields, one of the fields you can set is something like "custom", in that you can store whatever you like; so what you'd want to do is store something like a user's ID from a users table and how much of the virtual currency you want to give them and maybe separate this with a comma, so you can use explode() on the variable when it's returned to separate the data.

Once the PayPal payment is complete PayPal send an IPN (Instant Payment Notification), if you're using Express Checkout. This IPN request goes to a page that you specify, so you would need to create a http://yourwebsite.ca/ipn.php for example. This notification then needs to be validated and then you can extract the custom field, get the user id and the amount of virtual currency etc.. I suggest you use a pre-existing [PHP PayPal class](https://github.com/drewjoh/phpPayPal).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how to know that paypal who call/request my return url, not other trying to hack ?

Comment: If you take a look at that class you can see that it has a function called: do_authorization(), I believe this checks to see whether it's a valid request or not (whether it's PayPal or just something trying to get some free e-monies). Have a look at this [link](https://github.com/drewjoh/phpPayPal/wiki).

Comment: You do confuse the ExpressCheckout process with IPN. ExpressCheckout does not need to implement IPN. And the return url is only the second step in this process, where the site selling something asks Paypal if the payment was made, only then acts appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

The way this works with PayPal Instant Payment Notification - once you get the response from PayPal, you post the message back to PayPal and confirm that it was either VERIFIED or INVALID.

You do this post over HTTPS to PayPal, hence "Man in the Middle attacks" should not be an issue (which I think was your follow up question above). Please refer to the complete code sample for IPN [here](https://www.x.com/instant-payment-notification-4).

Answer (score 0):

What about a **system like this**:

1. When user add something to basket, or click a buy link, add a row to your own database with all the custom fields you need, then get the ID for the row (mysql_insert_id()).
2. Then have a hidden field in the PayPal form, which would be named `notify_url` and have it contain a link to something like `paypal_ipn.php?id={ID}` where `{ID}` is the database row ID.
3. After payment has been successful, PayPal will post the cart details to your script and you can get all the order details as well as using the `$_GET['id']` to retrieve the custom variables set in your database.

With the paypal_ipn.php script, you need to of course check the posted data is valid and make sure it's coming from PayPal itself and not being spoofed. Here is a good resource for your paypal_ipn.php file: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/using-paypals-instant-payment-notification-with-php/

Comment: Paypal IPN is not needed with the ExpressCheckout process. The finalization of the payment is triggered by the shop site after the user returned there.